# jQuery clone an image with a class of active and set it as background image of a div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am using twitter bootstrap's default carousel for a simple slider. What I want to achieve is that whichever item is active, the img inside that item should also be cloned and set as the background image of the div with the class of 'testimonials-bg'.

I have tried the following code but it does not seem to be working:

```
$("#testimonial-carousel .item.active").each(function() {

      var $myBg  = $(".testimonial-bg", this),
          $myImg = $(".testimonial-img img", this);

      $myBg.css({backgroundImage: "url('"+ $myImg[0].src +"')"});

    });
```

I have made a Fiddle for this: 
https://jsfiddle.net/4t17wxxw/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Subscribe to `slid.bs.carousel` event and change the background image to the active one:

```
var $myBg  = $(".testimonial-bg");

  $('#testimonial-carousel').on('slid.bs.carousel', function () {
      var $img = $('img','.carousel-inner>.item.active');
      $myBg.css({backgroundImage: "url('"+ $img[0].src +"')"});
      console.log($img[0].src);   
  });
```

[Working fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/4t17wxxw/6/)

Answer (score 0):

Your code is run only once when the script starts but you want to run it everytime the slide changes. Therefore, you can subscribe to the 'slid.bs.carousel' event which fires everytime the carousel displays a new slide.

You can read more about the event here: http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#carousel-events.

```
// Testimonial Background from active slide
$('#testimonial-carousel').on('slid.bs.carousel', function () {
  $("#testimonial-carousel .item.active").each(function() {
      var $myBg  = $(".testimonial-bg", this),
          $myImg = $(".testimonial-img img", this);

      $myBg.css({backgroundImage: "url('"+ $myImg[0].src +"')"});

    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no class called "testimonial-bg", here is the code which should call on each slide rotate or when you need to assign background image.

```
$("#testimonial-carousel .item.active").each(function() {
    $(this).css("background", "url('"+$(this).find(".testimonial-img img").attr('src')+"')" );
});
```

[Fiddle demo link](https://jsfiddle.net/4t17wxxw/9/)

Cheers